# Wildfly Maven Plugin shutdown and start an existing server

Tags: maven, wildfly

How do you configure wildfly maven plugin to shutdown and start an existing wildfly instance? It is downloading the server files and then starting the server. Another question is clean the right phase to use? What I would like is to able to just say hey maven redeploy and restart the server in one click.

I have the following below in my pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha11</version>
    <configuration>
        <force>true</force>
        <hostname>${jboss-as.deploy.hostname}</hostname>
        <username>${jboss-as.deploy.user}</username>
        <password>${jboss-as.deploy.pass.prod}</password>
        <fileNames>
             <fileName>target/${plugin.war.warName}.war</fileName>
        </fileNames>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>undeploy</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>undeploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>shutdown</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the start goal you just need to specify the [`<jboss-home/>`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/start-mojo.html#javaHome). That will start the server located in the path specified.

It depends on your use-case on what phase you bind to. There really is no right or wrong answer. However the `deploy` goal does require the `package` phase to be executed.

One other possible issue is the server may not be shutdown completely before the `start` goal is executed. Executing `shutdown` followed by a `start` goal is a bit of a race condition.

Comment: anyway to ensure that the shutdown goal is completed before the start goal starts?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Shutdown is a tough thing to "wait" for because you have to know what to wait for. The goal doesn't have access to the process so it won't know when it's destroyed. A best guess would be pinging the management port until you get denied, but even then it's not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I have spend a good portion of today figuring this issue out. Here is my solution, if it is still relevant for anyone:

```
<execution>
    <id>deploy</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <configuration>
        <jboss-home>/path/to/wildfly</jboss-home>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>

    <execution>
    <id>cleanup</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>undeploy</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
```

So, what happens here is we start server and deploy application in one 'step' (life cycle phase, to be more specific). and then after tests run, undeploy the application. The wildfly plugin is smart enough to figure out that it should shut down the server on its own. My wildfly plugin version is 1.1.0.Alpha5

Also, when I tried starting and deploying on separate phases, the server started twice and caused all sorts of problems for some reason.

I think this is the cleanest solution, unless you specifically want the server to be up in between tests.